# ls: unparsable value for LS_COLORS environment variable zshell in fedora 33

Tags: ls, coreutils

I'm using zshell in fedora 33 OS.

I've the [configuration](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Integralist/ProVim/master/.zshrc) in my `~/.zshrc` file

Whenever I run `ls` command I get below error -

```
ls: unparsable value for LS_COLORS environment variable
```

How can I fix this error?

LS_COLORS is correct when I do echo.

```
M. ~ 
○ echo $LS_COLORS
GxFxCxDxBxegedabagaced
```

Comment: No, `LS_COLORS` is not correct. `ls` tells you it's wrong. You need semicolons between entries. Read `man ls`.

Comment: @waltinator - thanks for your kind comment. Could you please let me know semi colon needed between which entries?

Comment: The correct syntax is like `rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:...` -- as produced by `dircolors`, see the man page; note that's colons between entries and semicolons between values _within an entry_.

Answer (score 5):

There are (at least) two common formats for ascribing colors to the output of `ls`. Your variable appears to contain the BSD-style format, which usually is given to the `LSCOLORS` environment variable. GNU tools use a different format (and helpfully renamed the variable to `LS_COLORS`).

You can use the `dircolors` tool to create an appropriate setting for the GNU-style variable.

Answer (score 3):

1. Start a shell
2. Run `unset LS_COLORS`
3. Run `dircolors -p > ~/.dircolors`
4. (optional) edit `~/.dircolors` to use the colours you prefer.  It's nicely commented and fairly easy to figure out.  If you use `vim` to edit it, syntax highlighting rules will show you what the colour codes will look like as you edit them.
5. Add the following to your `~/.zshrc` (and/or `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` if you're using bash) to cause your colour definitions to be loaded when a shell is started:

   ```
    [ -e ~/.dircolors ] && eval $(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors) || eval $(dircolors -b)
   ```

   Note 1: This should replace any existing code in `~/.zshrc` that acts to set `LS_COLORS`

   Note 2: You can make this system-wide (i.e. affecting all users) by editing the appropriate shell startup files under `/etc` instead of (or as well as) those in your home dir.  Read the man page for your shell for details.
6. This will only affect shells started after these changes.  To affect any currently running shell, run the same line in each terminal